# Create a drop down list in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, selectoption

I am trying to get a drop down option on my VF page with below code:

```
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectList value="{!countries}" multiselect="true">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectList><p/>

        <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
        <apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="testing...">
            <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <p>You have selected:</p>
                    <apex:dataList value="{!countries}" var="c">{!c}</apex:dataList>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class sampleCon {
    String[] countries = new String[]{};

    public PageReference test() {
        return null;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('GERMANY','GERMANY'));

        return options;
    }

    public String[] getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(String[] countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
}
```

But I see something like below instead of a picklist kind of field:

[image]

How to get this as a drop down list or like a picklist field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `size="1"`.

```
<apex:selectList size="1" ...>
```